# Функция для получения записей из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть функция, которая возвращает массив записей. Пытаюсь вытащить картинку пользователя, но она не выводится, что не так?

```
function uInfo ($id)
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");

if (!$query)
    die(mysql_error());

$n = mysql_num_rows($query);
$profile = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $profile[] = $row;
}   
return $profile;
}

$info = uInfo($id);
$user_img = $info['image'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Не одобряю я ваш подход к этой задаче, но дело ваше.*

Даже, если не обращать внимание на всё остальное, то в переменной **$profile**, а затем и в **$info**, у вас будет многомерный массив. И обращаться к нему надо соответствующе:

```
$user_img = $info[0]['image'];
```

В общем, если представить, что в мире не существует нормальных способов работы с БД и ваш способ - это практически единственное, что осталось, то должно быть как-то так:

```
function uInfo ($id) { 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
    if (!$query) die(mysql_error());
    $profile = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $profile[] = $row;
    }
    return $profile;
}

$info = uInfo($id);
$user_img_1 = $info[0]['image'];
$user_img_2 = $info[1]['image'];
/* ... */
$user_img_n = $info[n - 1]['image'];
```

Comment: в таком случае, подскажите нормальный способ, как можно ту же проблему решить иначе, с использованием функции.. это не сарказм, я правда не знаю как можно иначе или просто туплю

Comment: @xenon, для начала, надо бы знать, какие цели вы преследуете. Ваш пример - это для меня загадка. Если учесть, что поле **id** уникальное, то ваша функция умеет только вытаскивать одну запись из БД. Появляются вопросы... Зачем тогда прогонять функцию через цикл, если будет всего одна запись вытащена? Да и зачем функция вообще нужна? Вы эту опрецию будете делать в нескольких разных местах? И какая религия не дает вам использовать PDO? И даже, если хотите по старинке, то почему не экранируете данные в запросе? (*уже столько об этом писали...*)

Comment: на самом деле вытаскивать нужно всю информацию о пользователе из таблицы users, для краткости вопроса, сократил код

Comment: @xenon, я не говорил про данные одного поля )) Я говорил, что вытаскивается одна запись из таблицы. В вашем случае - это запись только одного пользователя: не двух, не трех, не сотни, а только одного юзверя.

Comment: ну а всё таки?) подскажите как реализовать функцию в моем случае?
З.Ы. на сайте у каждого пользователя есть свой профиль, ну и соответственно туда ему нужно выводить информацию о нем же (это что касается "для начала, надо бы знать, какие цели вы преследуете")

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно $info завар_дампить, посмотреть что внутри и решить проблему самому.